# TextInputAction.next not going to next field when has a suffixIcon in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with **TextFormField** using **TextInputAction.next**.

When I'm using suffixIcon the focus is on suffixIcon and not on the next field in my form.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to add a `Focus` widget to my suffixIcon and set the flags `canRequestFocus` and `descendantsAreFocusable` to false.

Example:

```
Widget _suffixIcon() {
  return Focus(
    canRequestFocus: false,
    descendantsAreFocusable: false,
    child: Icon(Icons.person), //Any icon or a custom widget
  );
}
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(suffix: _suffixIcon()),
  //...
)
```

Comment: above code is not working